# How to radio button size by vw unit?

Tags: html, css

I made an HTML code that has two radio buttons in it. All elements are designed with the vw unit. When I zoom in page the radio buttons transform by increasing the border size of it and finally become almost a big dot! When I delete the styles of radio buttons they become giant radio buttons when I zoom the page and make other elements move. Is there any solution to this problem? My code is given below

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <head/>

  <style>
    #field {
      width: 15vw;
      height: 15vw;
      border: 0.2vw solid black;
      padding-top: 1vw;
      padding-right: 1vw;
      padding-bottom: 1vw;
      padding-left: 1vw;
      margin-left: 0vw;
      margin-right: 0vw;
    }
    
    #txt {
      width: 10vw;
      font-size: 1.2vw;
      border: 0.2vw solid black;
    }
    
    #btn {
      width: 5vw;
      font-size: 1.2vw;
      border: 0.2vw solid black;
    }
    
    #rdo {
      width: 1.2vw;
      height: 1.2vw;
      border: 0.1vw solid black;
    }
    
    #br {
      font-size: 1vw;
    }
  </style>

  <body>

    <fieldset id="field" style="">

      <input type="text" id="txt" name="usr" placeholder="write something">
      <input type="radio" id="rdo" name="select" value="1">
      <br id="br" /> <br id="br" />
      <input type="button" id="btn" name="submit" value="click">
      <input type="radio" id="rdo" name="select" value="2">

    </fieldset>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Elements are supposed to increase in size when zooming in. That's the idea behind it, esp. important for vision impaired people. If you want to retain a *fixed* size values, don't make them dependent on viewport width or height (vh,vw,wmin,vmax). Another thing: `<input>` element sizes are by default defined in `em` units, making them dependent on the current `font-size`, so if you `font-size: 1.2vw` the element will grow/shrink depending on the font.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Right now when I zoom  in page other elements do not grow but radio buttons do. What can I do to prevent them grow?

Comment: Probably need to override all `#rdo` size related values, like `font-size, border-size`, etc. Check the radios with browser DevTools with all 'browser computed styles' active to find which size values you need to address.